# No Keyboard on Android Device Manager lock screen in Cubot X9 running Kitkat

Tags: locked-out, android-device-manager

I have locked myself out (forgot numeric PIN) of my Cubot X9 running Android 4.4 (probably, I am not 100% sure, but as it seems there is no vendor update on Lollipop available, and I definitively didn't update it manually).

So I logged in into Google's Android Device Manager and replaced my PIN code with the password specified in the form. It gets applied, as I see the new lock message, but there is no keyboard to input anything. It looks like this:

[image]

But no keyboard is showing. When I hit the return button or the home button I get back to a screen where I can enter a numeric pin (the original password)? But no letters are available.

If I press on "Emergency Call" and go back, I also come back to the PIN lock screen.

How can I enter my ADM password? Is there anyway to bypass the locked screen without losing data?